# Transactions hive or Hbase

Tags: hadoop, transactions, cassandra, hive, hbase

Transactions are more of row oriented correct me if I'm wrong. Hive or Hbase which of these is better for transactions?  Because updates are costly in hive ,Hbase is preferred. But Hbase is a columnar store. How each of them handles transactions when there are millions of them? 
Or are there better options ?

Comment: Both are not made for Transactions  .

Comment: @sandeeprawat So what exactly are used for transactions?

Comment: one question do you need to do this activity repeatably or it is on of the case ...

Comment: @sandeeprawat It's a repeating action

Comment: instead of doing  you task in transactions  do insert  into another table  (using what ever change you need to do ) drop your base table and rename /replace with your actual table .. but it will be very costly ....